# django queryset filter over tables

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have models like follows:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user = models.Foreignkey(User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'node'

class Thing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    begin_time = models.DateTimeField()
    node = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'thing'

class NodeLog(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(User)
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, related_name='nodelog_node')
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    result = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'node_log'
```

And data like follows:

```
table: node
+----+-------+---------+
| id | name  | user_id |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | node1 | 101     |
+----+-------+---------+
|  2 | node2 | 102     |
+----+-------+---------+

table: thing
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | begin_time          |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | 1       | 2015-01-01 03:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------------------+

table: thing_node
+----+----------+---------+
| id | thing_id | node_id |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | 1        | 1       |
+----+---------+----------+
|  2 | 1        | 2       |
+----+---------+----------+

table: node_log
+----+----------+---------+------------------------------+
| id | actor_id | node_id | action_time        |  result |
+----+----------+---------+------------------------------+
|  1 | 101      | 1       |2015-01-01 01:00:00 |  agree  |
|  2 | 102      | 2       |2015-01-01 02:00:00 |  agree  |
|  3 | 101      | 1       |2015-01-01 04:00:00 |  agree  |
+----+----------+---------+--------------------+---------+
```

If someone have agreed and his action_time is larger than begin_time, he can not agree again, so I do exclude like this:

```
Thing.objects.filter(***).exclude(node__nodelog_node__action_time__gt=F('begin_time'), node__nodelog_node__actor=request.user)
```

the request.user is 102, and the result is [].
The result of

```
Thing.objects.filter(***)
```

is right, any suggestion ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may lie in the fact that **exclude** does not behave like **filter**. In **exclude** the conditions do not need to hold together (i.e. are not and-ed)

[from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> The behavior of filter() for queries that span multi-value
>   relationships, as described above, is not implemented equivalently for
>   exclude(). Instead, the conditions in a single exclude() call will not
>   necessarily refer to the same item. For example, the following query
>   would exclude blogs that contain both entries with “Lennon” in the
>   headline and entries published in 2008:
>
> ```
> Blog.objects.exclude(
>     entry__headline__contains='Lennon',
>     entry__pub_date__year=2008,
> ) However, unlike the behavior when using filter(), this will not limit blogs based on entries that satisfying both conditions. In order
> ```
>
> to do that, i.e. to select all blogs that do not contain entries
>   published with “Lennon” that were published in 2008, you need to make
>   two queries:
>
> ```
> Blog.objects.exclude(
>     entry=Entry.objects.filter(
>         headline__contains='Lennon',
>         pub_date__year=2008,
>     ),
> )
> ```